# Is Jenkins parallel stages pipeline conditional flow, possible?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

So is it possible to run the Jenkins pipeline parallel conditionally? So i have a full build that runs all the stages in parallel, however lets say I only wanted to run 2/5 of the stages... is this possible, does anyone have an idea of what this syntax would look? Here is my groovy script:

```
def call() {
  def my_automation = load("my-lib/groovies/my_automation.groovy")
  parallel thing1: {
    stage('thing1'){
      my_automation.my_func("thing1")
    }},
    thing2: {
    stage('thing2'){
      my_automation.my_func("thing2")
    }}, thing3: {
    stage('thing3'){
      my_automation.my_func("thing3")
    }}, thing4: {
    stage('thing4'){
      my_automation.my_func("thing4")
    }}, thing5: {
    stage('thing5'){
      my_automation.my_func("thing5")
    }}, thing6: {
    stage('thing6'){
      my_automation.my_func("thing6")
    }}, thing7: {
    stage('thing7') {
      my_automation.my_func("thing7")
    }
  }
}return this;
```

But looking for this kind of thing:

```
for(all things defined, run them at once in parallel)
{
etc...
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is conditionally define what you want to pass to parallel, rather than processing it conditionally. You would use the for loop to build a map of the things you want to execute in a map, then pass that to the parallel step:

```
def branches = [:] 

for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
       int index = i

       branches["thing${index}"] = { 
           stage("thing${index}") {
               node ('label_example'){
                   my_automation.my_func("thing${index}")
               }
           }
       }

}

parallel branches
```

Use logic inside there to skip adding something to the map if you want. This isn't syntax checked or tested, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this, where i would pass in the image name and match it and this would decide on which one to run against (took long enough to respond, but figured this might help someone in the future):

```
String call(String image_name) {
  def map = ["CentOS-7":"rpm", "CentOS-6":"rpm", "RHEL-7":"rpm","RHEL-6":"rpm","Ubuntu-14.04":"deb"]
  for (element in map) {
    echo "${element.key} ${element.value}"
    if ("${element.key}" == image_name){
      return "${element.value}"}
  }
  return "notfound"
}
return this;
```